# Abstract class not loaded properly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, abstract-class, eager-loading

Here's my class hierarchy:

[image]

In my `Item` model, I have something like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    TYPES = [Weapon::TYPES, Armour::TYPES, Misc::TYPES].flatten.freeze
end
```

And then, the abstract classes are of the form:

```
class Misc < Item
    self.abstract_class = true

    TYPES = G_BASE_NAMES["misc"].keys.freeze
end
```

When I launch the console, I get:

> > /Users/hello_so/localhost/search/app/models/item.rb:7:in `': uninitialized constant Item::Misc

Line 7 in item.rb is the `TYPES = ...` line.

Why does it complain about Misc and not Weapon and Armour? (that appear first in the file btw)?

---

edit: I was actually doing that in an initializer (something I added just recently to try to fix the issue)

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/*.rb'].map {|f| File.basename(f, '.*').camelize.constantize }
end
```

If I remove it, then I can run the console.

---

Another strange thing:

```
$ rails c

> WEAPON

> NameError: uninitialized constant Weapon #why is it looking for the class??
> from /Users/hello_so/localhost/search/app/models/item.rb:7:in `<class:Item>'
```

But if I loaded `Item` (by typing `Item`), then it would complain about the WEAPON constant.

Comment: where is `Misc` defined? what if you do `::Misc::TYPES`?

Comment: Misc is in models/misc.rb, exact same for weapon and armour. I tried ::Misc.

Comment: It would just be Misc, if it's in models/misc.rb, not Item::Misc.

Comment: Kudos on the awesome diagram. +1 for that alone.

Comment: @Intelekshual Well, it complains about Item::Misc because it can't find the Misc class for some reason... If I use ::Misc, then it complains about Misc. By the way, when I remove Misc::TYPES and BASE_NAMES from the Item class, I can launch the console... I have no idea what's the difference between them.

Comment: I'd create `models/items` and namespace my objects in `Items` module

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about doing that. It's still really weird though. Can't find any differences...

Comment: I edited my question with some more infos.

Comment: I'm far from being an expert in Ruby loading logic, but from what I see, Ruby has troubles loading you classes. E.g. it starts loading Misc, sees that it depends on Item, starts loading Item, sees ::Misc::TYPES there, goes back to loading Misc, etc. Same circle if it starts with Item first.
Probably refer to the same G_BASE_NAMES["misc"].keys (and similar for weapon and armour) in your Item class, instead of using ::Misc::TYPES, ::Weapon::TYPES etc.

Comment: It could be something like that indeed. I ended up creating globals for every types, and using that instead. I need them in several places in the app, so it's not too bad. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to include your abstract class : `require Rails.root + path` ?

Comment: Be aware, `Rails.root` is a `Pathname`, not a `String`, and `Pathname`'s `+` operator is different. `path` should be a relative path, and not just the string you want to append. In particular, don't start it with a `/`, since that will be interpreted as "starting from the root of the filesystem" and the value of `Rails.root` will be thrown out.